# Adding context menu to richtextbox in a tab

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

This is the code for making a new tab with a rich text box in it and selecting the current richtextbox.

```
 private RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = null;
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        if (tp != null)
        {
            rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }

        return rtb;
    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
    }
```

I need to be able to add a context menu to the richtextbox, with cut, copy, paste and other controls I may need. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: `rtb.ContextMenuStrip = myContextMenuStrip;`

Comment: where is the context menu that you are wanting assign for example I would expect to see something like `rtb.ContextMenu = yourContextMenu` you know I would do a google search on the folllowing 
`C# stackoverflow add a context menu to the richtextbox winforms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you could add a ContextMenuStrip to your form, use the designer to define the menu items and then go to the RichTextBox properties and assign the ContextMenuStrip instance to the ContextMenuStrip property of the RichTextBox.

However you could create the same interface dynamically using code:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
ContextMenuStrip ctx = new ContextMenuStrip();
ctx.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Cut",null, cutClick));
ctx.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Copy", null, copyClick))
ctx.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Paste", null, pasteClick));
// Add other menu items as you need

rtb.ContextMenuStrip = ctx;
.....



void cutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
    if(rtb.SelectedText.Length > 0)
        rtb.Cut();
}
void copyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
    if(rtb.SelectedText.Length > 0)
       rtb.Copy();
}
void pasteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
    DataFormats.Format textFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text);
    if(rtb.CanPaste(textFormat))
        rtb.Paste();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was going to do at first, but I wasn't completely sure how. Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. Great answer.